# Presentation background not showing correctly

Tags: libreoffice

[This presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/Sheikh_Rehmat/economic-analysis-of-islamic-republic-of-iran?qid=6a5b007a-0df8-46b2-af71-273b9404d1b6&v=qf1&b=&from_search=9) has an almost transparent background, I downloaded it and opened it in the latest version of LibreOffice and the transparency is gone.

Do you know why this is happening and how to make LibreOffice open this presentation correctly?

I tried it on my brother's windows 7 laptop, and the presentation is showing correctly in powerpoint so the issue is with LibreOffice

**Edit**

maybe it's unrelated to libreoffice cause im having the same problem with kingsoft office, so how does Linux render documents?! Why is it different than Windows?

Comment: How did you even download it to your hard-drive? The save option only allows me to save it to my SlideShare account.

Comment: @Jobin it will send a link to your email to download it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not open the same as on Powerpoint, and I doubt that's possible to work around.  All of these presentation programs are great when used consistently, but they run into issues when trying to interpret closed formats that aren't made by the company that develops them.

If you can't make one of those programs your standard everywhere (you do realize there's Libreoffice and Kingsoft for Windows, right?) I'd recommend exporting it into a PDF and presenting it from that.  You won't be able to edit it, but that's what I'd do if all you're trying is to show it.

If the only problem is the background opacity (I doubt it, there's probably all manner of weird glitches), you can change the opacity of the background in Libreoffice - go into 'Master View' to edit the slide templates, and you can mess with the uneditable background content as if it were just text and images.

Comment: My presentations are handed to my professors at my university, those dudes use powerpoint, and they require me to present a powerpoint presentation to them. So I can't play with the presentations too much, it's not important how a presentation looks on my pc, what matters is how it looks on their pc when they open it in powerpoint

Comment: Are you creating it in Libreoffice, then?  I know that export to .ppt, esp .pptx is pretty awful.

Comment: sometimes i create it in libreoffice, other times i am required to get a powerpoint from a colleague who uses windows powerpoint, edit it and present it, if I'm working in a group for example

Comment: I feel you - been in the same situation.  Libreoffice just isn't good working back and forth with Powerpoint docs.  Is Kingsoft any better - I've not played with it much.

Comment: no, same problem :(

Comment: Meh.  All I could suggest is fiddle with it until it looks good in both, or bribe your profs to let you use a PDF.

Comment: That's the problem with going to/from closed standards from open software.

Comment: Is the original file in ppt format? Libreoffice breaks several proprietary format files. Try exporting it to `.odp` from Microsoft Office and then open it with libreoffice.

Comment: @ssoto it's `.pptx`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a `.pptx` file format you should export to Libreoffice format. Then you can open it good.

Comment: how to export it? from powerpoint?

Comment: cant export it to odp from within LibreOffice

Comment: @Fischer yes, export from PowerPoint. Libreoffice can't read `.pptx` format :(

Comment: so I have to install powerpoint on wine to be able to export it, and then workon on it in LibreOffice, better just install powerpoint on wine and work on it from there

Comment: @Fischer I tried that, but there are many problems. But now I've installed a Windows virtualbox machine and then install Office insde it.

Comment: @Fischer the message is: require others to use open formats :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want 100% compatibility, either ditch MS-PPT or create all your presentations using LibreOffice. LO support for special and rarely used features, is far from perfect. If you need your presentations to be compatible, I would recommend using Wine or create your presentation in LibreOffice from the start.

I would also recommend to fill a bug report in [LO bug tracker](https://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/bug/) so they know which features are missing.